# Reference request: Triangle geometry (for IMO-type problems) and various other subject areas

Tags: geometry, reference-request, contest-math

I am a beginner in studying centroid, circumcenter, incenter, and locus of a point. Is there any book that could make me understand their fundamentals well and be able to solve most of their proofs? and then to be able to solve IMO problems?

And what is the best way to be good at mathematics? What books should I study in each field: algebra, geometry, number theory, algebraic geometry, and combinatorics?

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Olympiad_books

Comment: do they contain books for beginners ?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AmirHossein already gave you a link above to a list of books of several fields. So, I will refrain from pointing you to other books. I will only try to answer your final question "And what is the best way to be good at mathematics?":

In order to become good at mathematics you have to *do* mathematics. This means, you have to try to solve problems, you have to fail solving them, give it yet another try until you ultimately come to a solution.

In some respects mathematics is like swimming: you won't learn it by watching other people doing it. You have to jump into the deep oceans of mathematics and try it yourself. Even though it might be frustrating much of the time, it is well worth the effort. You will end up diving far under the surface and you will be able to see a beautiful world which is hidden to most people. I can only encourage you to jump into the water and start doing mathematics.

Comment: thanks for your advice , I am looking forward to studying Olympiad topics and books because they are very interesting, but in most of the times I have a great difficulty in studying them , and many times I don't even understand the solution so what do you suggest: to read many solutions to problems until I become comfortable with these topics Or to try to search theorems and study them and " struggle" with the problems for some time before I see the answer even though I am beginner ??